# Adding a hyperlink to a cell

Tags: google-sheets

Can I embed an inlined URL into a cell? Example:

```
Moving to debug/security (PR)
```

Where `PR` is a URL, and the rest of the text is literal.

The `HYPERLINK` formula did not work:

```
Moving to debug/security (HYPERLINK("pr.com","PR))
```

I guess `HYPERLINK` only works when it's the only content inside of the cell. E.g. `=HYPERLINK(...)`

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to include a hyperlink in-line with other cell content can't as in Google Sheets, cells can't contain hypertext (combination of text , hyperlinks and media like images, video and audio).